# Blobstore Together with Other Input in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I understand that uploading blob in Google App Engine is something like this:

```
<%
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
%>

<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Is it possible to save other input field? Let say we have other input in a form.

```
<input type="text" name="str" />
```

Comment: you can get text field data and store it in text/plain for example then store it on blobstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is possible. I'm successfully doing what you're asking about - uploading files and text on the same request in GAE. You just handle the request and its parameters in your request handler.